# Sufficient condition for real roots of a polynomial of order $n>5$ with arbitrary real coefficients

Tags: constrained-optimization, polynomials, roots, rootfinding

I ask for help in solving the problem. I am developing an optimization program that selects the coefficients of a polynomial of order $n> 5$ so that all its zeros are just real numbers. And I cannot find sufficient conditions suitable for this, which would include its coefficients.

In the article [A Sufficient Condition for All the Roots of a Polynomial To Be Real](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2325063)  conditions are given that seem to indicate whether the zeros of the polynomial are valid. But there are also counterexamples when the condition is satisfied, but the polynomial has zeros with a nonzero imaginary part. A modification of the method is intended only for polynomials with positive coefficients. I am working with polynomials that have arbitrary real coefficients.

Therefore, I need sufficient conditions for the validity of zeros for such a case. Who can suggest anything?

Comment: The closest way I know of for testing if a univariate polynomial has a given number of real roots is to use a real root isolation algorithm/test, for example Sturm's theorem. Unfortunately, these methods typically require "exact" math, which I think means your coefficients are limited to rationals represented with arbitrary length integer pairs.

Comment: @helloworld922 The tip about the test for the number of real roots is very good. It can be done not only with the help of Sturm's theorem, but also by compiling a symmetric Hermite matrix by the coefficients of the polynomial and calculating its signature. https://mathoverflow.net/a/30533/148731

Comment: https://arxiv.org/pdf/2012.03530.pdf if you have time, please read this work